# Prove that $1\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!\left(-1\right)^{1+k}}{\left(n-k\right)!k^{k}}$

Tags: calculus

Do you know how to prove that

$$ 1 \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\left(n-1\right)!\left(-1\right)^{1+k}}{\left(n-k\right)!k^{k}} \quad ?? $$

Any help is appreciated.

**My attempt.** I tried showing that the first term is $1$ and that the terms are all decreasing from there, i.e.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!\left(-1\right)^{1+k}}{\left(n-k\right)!k^{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{\left(n+1-1\right)!\left(-1\right)^{1+k}}{\left(n+1-k\right)!k^{k}}\ge0$$

But I was unable to make it simplify nicely. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The terms decrease because of the $(n-k)!k^k$ in the denominator, hence the sum must be $\leq 1$

Answer (score 3):

We have

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!k^{k}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{k-1}e^{-kt} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} t^{k-1}e^{-kt} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - te^{-t})^{n-1} e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Now, a simple calculation shows that $0 \leq te^{-t} \leq e^{-1} < 1$ for $t \geq 0$. Hence,

$$ 0 \leq (1 - te^{-t})^{n-1} \leq 1 $$

and this implies the last integral is bounded by

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t = 1. $$